# How do you add a page break on a specific row in a tablix in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've got an old report that was built with a tablix wrapped around everything else in the report. Inside this "master" tablix are other tablixes. For one of the nested tablixes I want to add a page break before it. I've tried wrapping the nested tablix in a rectangle and setting page break before to true and I've tried setting page break before to true for the nested tablix itself. Neither of these has any effect.

I also tried adding a parent row group and using this expression: =CEILING(RowNumber(Nothing)/14) since I want it to break on the 14th row but this also did not work correctly and just inserted random breaks all over the place.

In the master tablix there is a blank row between the nested tablix I need a page break before and a preceeding nested tablix. Is there a way to set that row to always have a page break? Can I put some kind of expression in one of the cells of the blank row that forces a page break?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a filter on the row (tablix properties) to break on the 14th row. See below:

[image]

This will prevent the table from displaying more than 14 rows.

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Gav